# Run WAR with special user?

Tags: permissions, java, users, jboss

I have a Java WAR file that I run over JBoss Wildfly Application Server on Ubuntu. Now, this WAR accesses the file system and I'd like to only let it do that over a certain user. Is that possible? I might also have other WAR files running on the same Wildfly server, but those shall run on different users.
Is this idea possible?

**EDIT 1:**

Say I have 5 WAR files that I want to run on 1 Wildfly server at the same. Is it possible to run:

- one WAR with the user `usera`,
- the second WAR with `userb`,
- the third WAR with `userc`,
- the fourth WAR with `userd`, and
- the fifth WAR with `usere`?

Of course provided all the users exist.

Comment: Did you create the WAR file?

Comment: @Rinzwind I thought that was clear in my posting. Please view EDIT 1.